# Mostrar primer multiplo de dos numeros

Tags: javascript, html, condiciones

El ejercicio consiste en ingresar dos numeros y mostrar el primer numero entre esos dos que sea multiplo de 4 y 6 a la vez. El problema que tengo es que no logro mostrar solo el primer numero y entonces se muestran todos los multiplos de 4 y 6. Por ejemplo si los numeros ingresados son el 1 y el 50 deberia mostarse solamente el 12 pero se muestra el 12,24,36 y 48.
Los valores ingresados son mediante HTML y el resulatdo se muestra cuando aprieto un boton.
Mi codigo HTML es el siguiente:

```
<label for="val1">Ingrese valor 1</label>
<input type="number" id="val1"><br>
<label for="val2">Ingrese valor 2</label>
<input type="number" id="val2"><br>
<input type="button" id="btnEj16" value="Mostrar">

<p id="resultado"></p>
```

Y mi codigo JS es el siguiente:

```
window.addEventListener("load", inicio);

function inicio(){
    document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", ejercicio)
}

function ejercicio(){
    let valor1 = Number(document.querySelector("#val1").value);
    let valor2 = Number(document.querySelector("#val2").value);

    if(valor2>valor1){
        for (let i = 1; i<=valor2; i++) {
            if (i % 4 === 0 && i % 6 ===0) {
                document.querySelector("#resultado").innerHTML += `${i}<br>`
            }
        }   
    }


    if(valor1>valor2){
        for (let i = 1; i<=valor1; i++) {
            if (i % 4 === 0 && i % 6 ===0) {
                document.querySelector("#resultado").innerHTML += `${i}<br>`
            }
        }   
    }

}
```

Agradezco ayuda

Comment: Ponle un `break` despues de cada `document.querySelector("#resultado").innerHTML += \`${i}<br>\`` para que detenga los ciclos cuando encuentre el primero